# Changing colors via button clicks

Tags: 3d-view, constraints, blend-files, blend4web

Well I want to change colors of the blender models by button clicks in the web app I am making. Kind of like the html color picker. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: When you click a colour property you get a [colour picker pop-up](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/extended_controls.html#color-picker)

Comment: sorry about that.. my question was incomplete.. I want the colors to change via button clicks in a browser window..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a combo of Blend4Web's [Switch Select](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/logic_editor.html#switch-select) and [Set Shader Node Param](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/logic_editor.html#set-shader-node-param) logic nodes.

Feel free to ask for an example blend file on the B4W forums.

Answer (score -2):

Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=wObgpd2pSpI), I hope it serves you.